# How do I call these methods?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and I'm trying to call the private methods I've set up earlier, but with no success. It's a simple program that generates random numbers and display messages. Anyone wants to lend a hand?
Sorry if the code is bad, I've only been learning this for less than month.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project2 {
    
    private static int rollDie() {
        int num_random2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        System.out.println("Die 2: " + num_random2);
        return num_random2;
    }
    
    private static int rollDie2() {
        int num_random = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        System.out.println("Die 1: " + num_random);
        return num_random;
    }

    private static void printDice(int num_random, int num_random2) {
        total = num_random + num_random2;
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    }

    int total = num_random + num_random2;

    private static void printSpecialMessage(int total) {
        String message1 = "Snake Eyes";
        String message2 = "Box cars";
        if (total = 12) {
            System.out.println(message2);
        } else if (total = 2) {
            System.out.println(message1);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to my app!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Dice Roller");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String choice = "y";

        do {
        
            rollDie();
            rollDie2();
            printDice();
            printSpecialMessage();

            System.out.print("Roll Again? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            System.out.println();
            
        }
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

```
The method printDice(int, int) in the type project2 is not applicable for the arguments ()     
    The method printSpecialMessage(int) in the type project2 is not applicable for the arguments ()

    at project2.main(project2.java:51)
```

At this point I'm about to just give up. Hopefully someone can help me out!

Comment: A couple of things right off the bat: `if (total = 12)` the equality operator is `==`, not `=`. Also `int total = num_random + num_random2;` makes me think you expect that line to be executed after the method definitionss that are just above it are called. That's not how it works. You'll have to do it where you call the methods, in the main, something like `int total = rollDie() + rollDie2;`, then `printSpecialMessage` needs to accept `total` as a parameter so that it can do its stuff.

Comment: About the error message, it seems pretty clear: you defined `printDice` to accept two parameters but you're not calling it with two parameters. You'll need to save the results of `rollDie` and `rollDie2` inside a variable (like `int roll1 = rollDie();`) and then pass those variables to the method when you call it.

Comment: More generally, there are *a lot* of wrong things in this code. I'd suggest you give another read to whatever textbook/tutorial you're using to learn java. If that doesn't clarify your doubts, try with another textbook/tutorial. If you haven't tried it already I'd suggest the tutorials on Oracle's website: in particular [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) and [this other one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Few errors in your code I found.

1. `if (total = 12)` should be replaced with `if (total == 12)`.

   Make sure you always use two equals in if condition. One = is for assignment and two = for condition check.
2. printDice() -> The signature is not matching. Pass two values to this function.
3. total should be declared as static.
4. printSpecialMessage -> The signature is not matching. Pass one values to this function.

I suggest you start with writing simple code and then gradually go ahead with writing complex codes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile. The following code does. Compare it with your code.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project2 {

    private static int rollDie() {
        int num_random2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        System.out.println("Die 2: " + num_random2);
        return num_random2;
    }

    private static int rollDie2() {
        int num_random = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        System.out.println("Die 1: " + num_random);
        return num_random;
    }

    private static void printDice(int num_random, int num_random2) {
        int total = num_random + num_random2;
        total = num_random + num_random2;
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    }

    private static void printSpecialMessage(int total) {
        String message1 = "Snake Eyes";
        String message2 = "Box cars";
        if (total == 12) {
            System.out.println(message2);
        }
        else if (total == 2) {
            System.out.println(message1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to my app!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Dice Roller");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "y";
        do {
            int one = rollDie();
            int two = rollDie2();
            printDice(one, two);
            printSpecialMessage(one + two);

            System.out.print("Roll Again? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            System.out.println();
        } while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
}
```

The things I changed (in no particular order).

1. Method `printSpecialMessage` requires an argument. You call that method from method `main` without an argument. Hence the following [compiler] error.

   > The method printSpecialMessage(int) in the type Project2 is not applicable for the arguments ()
2. Similarly for method `printDice`. That method requires two arguments but you call it with no arguments, which gives the following [compiler] error.

   > The method printDice(int, int) in the type Project2 is not applicable for the arguments ()
3. You need to save the value returned from method `rollDie` in a variable. You also need to save the value returned from method `rollDie2` in another variable. Then you call method `printDice` with those two variables as arguments. In the code above I named the variables `one` and `two`.
4. `break` is not used in `if` statements. See method `printSpecialMessage`.
5. When comparing integers, use `==` (double equals sign). Again see method `printSpecialMessage`.
6. The following line of code is not inside the body of a method. It belongs in method  `printDice`.

```java
int total = num_random + num_random2;
```

Here is a sample run of the above code.

```
Welcome to my app!

Dice Roller

Die 2: 5
Die 1: 3
Total: 8
Roll Again? (y/n): y

Die 2: 6
Die 1: 3
Total: 9
Roll Again? (y/n): n
```